# JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb

Tags: ios, jpeg

I am developing a app in which i have to show video streaming from ip cam, i have used SPMJPEG stream for same. Here is my code snippet--

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

@try
{

[_receivedData appendData:data];

NSRange beginRange = [_receivedData rangeOfData:_beginMarkerData
                                        options:0
                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, _receivedData.length)];

NSRange endRange = [_receivedData rangeOfData:_endMarkerData
                                      options:0
                                range:NSMakeRange(beginRange.location+beginRange.length,     _receivedData.length - (beginRange.location+beginRange.length))];


if(endRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
long endLocation = endRange.location + endRange.length;

if (_receivedData.length >= endLocation)
{
//Getting data in imageData in both iOS 7 and iOS 8
NSData *imageData = [_receivedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(beginRange.location,     endLocation-beginRange.location)];

            [_receivedData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, endLocation) withBytes:NULL length:0];

UIImage *receivedImage = nil;
//Getting data in receivedImage in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8, returning nil image in iOS 8
receivedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

if (receivedImage)
{
            static double movieSize = 0;
            movieSize += imageData.length;

            NSLog(@"Frame size in kb: %f, since begining: %f", imageData.length / 1024.0, movieSize / 1024.0);

            double delay = (!lastFrameDate) ? 0 : -[lastFrameDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

            lastFrameDate = [NSDate date];

            self.frame = [SPMJPEGFrame frameWithImage:receivedImage timeDelay:delay];
        }
    }
}
       }
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warnning!" message:[e description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;

}
}
```

It was working pretty good in iOS 7 but its not working in iOS 8 at all, i am getting error "ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb" but it was not an issue in iOS 7 but as i got to know from googling that iOS 8 does not allow to display corrupted JPEG images in UIImageView.(i am using UIImageView to show stream url)Please help me regarding same, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon similar complaints, the IOS 8 JPEG decoder sounds like it is more stringent than the IOS 7 version. My own theory is that some encoder inserting extra bytes after a counted marker. So far no one has taken the time to identify:

1. What application is creating these JPEG images
2. What marker is causing the problem

FFDB is a Define Quantization Table Marker. Maybe you could tell use what is creating the JPEG files and you could run some type of JPEG dump program to analyze the structure of the stream.I suspect that you will find:

```
   FF<Marker ID><2-byte length = L><L bytes of data><2 more bytes>FFDB
```

My wager is that problem marker is a bad EXIF header.

In the mean time, likely solutions are:

a. Using a different JPEG encoder
 b. Writing a simple filter that removes excess bytes in a JPEG stream.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, i don't have enough knowledge about JPEG's, **Can we remove excess bytes in a JPEG stream**, if you have any info about it please share with me, Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to do some analysis here. I would get a JPEG dumping program that analyzes the structure of the file to be sure my theory is reality. If I am right, the way to do is is create a simple filter that recognizes the various JPEG markers and can identify those with lengths. It would then copy the jpeg stream using lengths and ignoring extra bytes.